# Return Subscript in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

I am trying to return a JSON object via AJAX using jQuery, that may contain elements that need HTML Tags. It is not great practice to include HTML tags within a JSON response and even so, it will be encoded at the other end so may cause more problems.

Consider this result:

```
{
    "Country_Code":"EL",
    "Country_Name":"Greece",
    "Total_Value":5,
    "Formatted_Value":"5m3"
}
```

The 'Formatted_Value' needs to look like this: 5m<sup>3</sup>. **My question is simply, what would be the best way to achieve this with a returned JSON object?**

If HTML is the best way then I will implement this, but only as a last resort as returning markup in a JSON request is not very good.

Comment: If you don't do this on server, just do it on frontend. `response["Formatted_Value"] = response["Formatted_Value"].replace(/^(\d+[a-z]{1,2})(\d+)/i, '$1<sup>$2</sup>')`

Comment: That is helpful but is too static to work in way that I want it too. I effectively want any html entity to display correctly, not just <sup> tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could change the Json in this way:

```
"Formatted_Value":"5m&sup3;"
```

Using `&sup3;` (³) entity: http://code.google.com/p/doctype-mirror/wiki/Sup3CharacterEntity

Comment: This looks very promising and was in fact the sort of answer I was looking for :-) Will test and see if it works.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent jQuery from encoding HTML elements, as it is displaying as `&sup3;` instead of ³?